# Are there any scriptures that portray Lord Rama to be the source of all incarnations including Lord Vishnu?

Tags: scripture, rama, avatars, identification-request

There are many verses in the Srimad Bhagavatam and the Brahma-Vaivarta Purana which are used by Krishna-centric Vaishnava traditions to show that Lord Krishna is the source of all incarnations, including of Lord Vishnu. Some of such verses are:

> *ete cāṁśa-kalāḥ puṁsaḥ **kṛṣṇas tu bhagavān svayam** indrāri-vyākulaṁ
>   lokaṁ mṛḍayanti yuge yuge* (Srimad Bhagavatam 1.3.28)
>
> **English Translation**: All of the above-mentioned incarnations are either plenary portions or portions of the plenary portions of the Lord, **but Lord Śrī Kṛṣṇa is the original Personality of Godhead**. All of them appear on planets whenever there is a disturbance created by the atheists. The Lord incarnates to protect the theists.
>
> ---
>
> *narayanas tvam na hi sarva-dehinam
>   atmasy adhisakhila-loka-saksi
>   **narayano ’ngam** nara-bhu-jalayanat
>   tac capi satyam na tavaiva maya* (Srimad Bhagavatam 10.14.14)
>
> **English Translation**: Are You not the original Narayana, O supreme controller, since You are the Soul of every embodied being and the eternal witness of all created realms? Indeed, **Lord Narayana is Your expansion**, and He is called Narayana because He is the generating source of the primeval water of the universe. He is real, not a product of Your illusory Maya.

I am not mentioning the verses from the Brahma-Vaivarta Purana as there are too many to quote.

In addition to the these two Puranas, Gaudiya Vaishnavas use the Brahma Samhita, the famous text containing Lord Brahma's prayers to Lord Krishna that was discovered by Chaitanya Mahaprabhu in Adi-Keshava Temple, to reiterate their point of Lord Krishna to be the Original Supreme Personality of Godhead.

So are there any scriptures which say Lord Rama is the source of all incarnations? I have heard that Ramanandi Vaishnavas believe Lord Rama to be the source of all incarnations. Do they have any scriptural evidence to support their view?

Comment: Ramacaritamaanasa.

Comment: Related [Is concept brahman mentioned anywhere in Valmiki Ramayana?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23257/is-concept-brahman-mentioned-anywhere-in-valmiki-ramayana/23262#23262)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, there are scriptures that are used by Ramanandi Vaishnavas to support their claim of Lord Rama being the Original Supreme Personality of Godhead.

> ***raghavasya guno divyo mahavisnuh svarupavana*** ।
>
> *vasudevo ghanibhutastanutejah sadasivah* ।।
>
> *matsyasca ramahrdayam yogarupi janardanah* ।
>
> *kurmascadharasaktisca varaho bhujayorbalam* ।।
>
> *narasimho mahakopo vamanah katimekhala* ।
>
> *bhargavo jamnghayorjato balaramasca prsthatah* ।
>
> *bauddhastu karuna saksat kalkiscittasya harsatah* ।।
>
> *krsnah srrngararupasca vrndavanavibhusanah* ।।
>
> ***aite camsakalah sarve ramo brahma santanah*** । (**Sudarshana Samhita 1-5**)
>
> **English Translation**: **When the infinite divine auspicious qualities of Lord Rama takes form, He becomes MahaVishnu**. Shri Rama's auspicious condensed divine splendour is Lord Vasudeva. Matsya avatara appeared from Shri Rama's heart, Kurma avatara is the manifestation of His support-power. Varaha is the manifestation of His arm's strength. Lord Narasimha appears from His anger, Lord Vamana from His waist, Lord Parashurama appears from His thigh, Buddha from His compassion, Kalki appears from His delight and the Vrindavana-Vihari Shri Krishna Himself is His Shringaar Swaroopa. **Thus, all these incarnations are are either plenary portions or portions of the plenary portions of Lord Rama and Lord Rama is the origin, the eternal Brahman and the original Supreme Personality of Godhead Himself.**
>
> ---
>
> ***yatha sarvavataranamavatari raghuttamah*** ।
>
> *tatha strotasam saumya pavini sarayu sarita* ।। (**Agastya Samhita, Uttara-Khanda**)
>
> **English Meaning**: Shri Rama, the best among the Raghus, **is the original Supreme Personality of Godhead, among all the incarnations**; in the same way as the divine river Sarayu is the greatest among all rivers.
>
> ---
>
> avatarastu bahavah kala amsavibhutayah ।
>
> ***ramodhanurdharah saksat sarveso bhagavan svayam*** ।। (**Shiva Samhita**)
>
> **English Translation**: Various incarnations are either plenary portions or portions of the plenary portions of the Lord, **but Lord Rama who wields the bow is the God of all Gods and the original Supreme Personality of Godhead Himself**.
>
> ---
>
> ***purnopurnavatarasca syamoramoraghuttamah*** ।
>
> ***amsanrsimhakrsnadyah raghavobhagavansvayam*** ।। (**Yajnavalkya Samhita**)
>
> **English Translation**: **Lord Rama is the best among the Raghus is the original Supreme Personality of Godhead and also a complete incarnation. Narasimha, Krishna and others the plenary portions of Raghava, the original Supreme Personality of Godhead.**
>
> ---
>
> ***nārāyaṇō'pirāmāṃśaḥ-śaṅkhacakragadādharaḥ***॥ (**Varaha Samhita**)
>
> **English Translation:** Lord Narayana, the wielder of Shankha, Chakra, Gada and Padma **is the first manifestation of Bhagavan Shri Rama.**

Source: http://lordrama.co.in

Comment: Nice answer!... btw what are these Samhitas?.. are they Agamas or they are part of Puranas?..

Comment: @Tezz I guess then its from the Agamas.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury I checked your reference of the Shiva Samhita but I cannot find this verse. Can you give the chapter/verse number?

Comment: @Wikash_hindu Which version of Shiva Samhita are you using?

Comment: This one:    https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://nitayoga.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Yoga-Shiva-Samhita.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwj6vczerKvgAhXHY1AKHeqLADwQFjABegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw0A2wxbJsYLVNOEqCmuxNEA

Comment: I think I used the wrong samhita since this is about yoga. Could you give the specific verse and chapter number?

Comment: @Wikash_hindu I don't have the specific verse and chapter number. I quoted it from a site.

Comment: This shiva samhita is actually narad pancharatra which is extinct. There is other book namned as same shiva samhita . Note this book is for yoga only.

Answer (score 18):

Yes. Other scriptures too mention Rama as source of incarnation. What say more, the Supreme Empress of Universe Mother Durga Herself reminded the Supreme Eternal Shri Raama of His prowess and infinite strength.

When Shri Hari along with Lakshmana performed the NavaRatri Vratam to get victory over Ravana and to get back the Supreme Goddess of Universe Mother Sita, then His sister Parameshvari Durga came and blessed Him that His desires would be completed.

On the eight day of Navaratri Vrata, Mother Paraambika came to the Supreme Lord Parameshvara Shri Raama and told Him thus:

> **Devi Puraana, Book 3, Chapter 30**
>
> देव्युवाच ।
>   राम राम महाबाहो तुष्टाऽस्म्यद्य व्रतेन ते ॥ ४६ ॥
>   प्रार्थयस्व वरं कामं यत्ते मनसि वर्तते ।
>   नारायणांशसम्भूतस्त्वं वंशे मानवेऽनघे ॥ ४७ ॥
>   रावणस्य वधायैव प्रार्थितस्त्वमरैरसि ।
>   पुरा मत्स्यतनुं कृत्वा हत्वा घोरञ्च राक्षसम् ॥ ४८ ॥
>   त्वया वै रक्षिता वेदाः सुराणां हितमिच्छता ।
>   भूत्वा कच्छपरूपस्तु धृतवान्मन्दरं गिरिम् ॥ ४९ ॥
>   अकूपारं प्रमन्थानं कृत्वा देवानपोषयः ।
>   कोलरूपं परं कृत्वा दशनाग्रेण मेदिनीम् ॥ ५० ॥
>   धृतवानसि यद्‌राम हिरण्याक्षं जघान च ।
>   नारसिंहीं तनुं कृत्वा हिरण्यकशिपुं पुरा ॥ ५१ ॥
>   प्रह्लादं राम रक्षित्वा हतवानसि राघव ।
>   वामनं वपुरास्थाय पुरा छलितवान्बलिम् ॥ ५२ ॥
>   भूत्वेन्द्रस्यानुजः कामं देवकार्यप्रसाधकः ।
>   जमदग्निसुतस्त्वं मे विष्णोरंशेन सङ्गतः ॥ ५३ ॥
>   कृत्वान्तं क्षत्रियाणां तु दानं भूमेरदाद्‌द्विजे ।
>   तथेदानीं तु काकुत्स्थ जातो दशरथात्मज ॥ ५४ ॥
>   प्रार्थितस्तु सुरैः सर्वै रावणेनातिपीडितैः ।
>
> Devi said-
>   **O Rama! O Rama with great strength! Today I am satisfied with Thy Vrata. Do ask Me the desired wish which existeth in Thy mind.** 46.
>
> **O Rama! By taking part from Narayana Thou manifestedst Thyself in the sinless clan of Manu. And Thou art prayed by all Immortal Devas for slaying of Raavana.** 47.
>
> **It was Thou Who in ancient times tooketh body of fish and killing the terrible Rakshasa Hayagriva only by Thee the Vedas were saved for welfare of Suras.** 48.
>
> **It was Thou Who incarnatedth in form of tortoise and heldeth aloft the Mandara mountain, churnedth the ocean and nourishedth the Devas.** 49.
>
> **O Rama! Thou tookest Supreme form of Boar and 
>   heldest aloft the Earth on the front of Thy teeth, and annihilatedst Hiranyaksha.** 50.
>
> **Thou assuming the form of a Man-Lion and preserving Prahlaada, O Rama Who art Descent of Raghu! annihilatedst HiranyaKashipu, in ancient times.** 51.
>
> **It was Thou Who in ancient times becameth the younger brother to Indra and manifesting as a dwarf body deceitfully cheatedth Bali, for well conferring favour to the Devas.** 52.
>
> **Thou by the combination of My and Vishnu's part, incarnatedst as the Son of Jamadagni, extirpatedst the lines of Ksattriya kings and gavest over this whole earth to Bhagavan Kashyapa Risi.** 53.
>
> **So Thou art now born as the son of Dasarath in clan of Kakutstha, being prayed by all the Devas as they are much harassed by Ravana.** 54.

Comment: Welcome back ...

Comment: Means more active participation

Answer (score 14):

Yes there are verses in scriptures which Declare Lord Rama as source of all Incartions.

> **Salutations to that Rama who is most superior, the primal Lord of Universe and free from all the vices. Brahma, Vishnu and Mahesh who are sustainer of the world are just parts of Lord Rama.** (**Skanda Purana, Uttara kanda, Ramayana Mahatmya 1.3**)
>
> The renowned Rama is capable of totally destroying all the worlds together with its five elements, along with its animate and inanimate things and also to create yet again all the worlds in like manner as before." (**Valmiki Ramayana 5.51.39**)
>
> Killing of demons with bow and arrows, or building a bridge over the ocean does not constitute the factual Glory of the Supreme Personality Of Godhead, Lord Rama,whose spiritual body is always engaded in various past times. There is no one equal to Lord Rama and therefore he had no need to take help from the monkeys to gain victory over demon Ravana. (**Srimad Bhagavatam 9-11-20**)
>
> Shri Hanuman says- I worship all times Lord Rama, who is eternal and who is very form sat existence and Amanda bliss. Shri Rama is expert in the rasaleela, His parts are Brahma, Vishnu, Mahesh who are sustainers of the world.(**Hanuman Samhita**)

In Aadi-Ramayana, Lord Hanuman says to Garuda

> I do not know any other supreme being, the God of all gods. All the **innumerable incarnations have originated from Lord Rama alone.**

In Valmiki Ramayana Lord Rama is discribed as powerful as Lord Shiva

> अब्रवीच्च तदा रामः सुग्रीवं प्रत्यनन्तरम् | विभीषणं च धर्मात्मा हनूमन्तं च वानरम् || ९३-६-३७ जाम्बवन्तं हरिश्रेष्ठं मैन्दं द्विविदमेव च | एतदस्त्रबलन् दिव्यं मम वा त्र्यम्बकस्य वा || ९३-६-३८
>
> Then, the virtuous Rama spoke also to the Sugreeva, Vibhishana, Hanuman the monkey, Jambavan, Mainda the foremost of monkeys and even Dvivida, who were in close proximity to him as follows "**Such wonderful power of this missile exists either with me or with the three-eyed Rudra the Lord of destruction**."

Comment: I think he questioned about Rama being the source of all incarnations(Dasavataras)

Answer (score 6):

The 33 Vishwedevas are the supreme beings which form the divine forces of the universe. These are the 8 vasus, 11 Rudras, 12 Adityas, Prajapati and Brihaspati.

Sri Rama was born under Punarvasu Nakshatra whose reiging deity is Aditi-Devata.  Aditi-Devata is considered the mother of 12 Nakshatra's which formed during creation of a new manvantara from the 12 Adityas. One among this is Vishnu( Vamana) or commonly known as Sravana.

Sri Krishna was born under Rohini nakshtra. The reigning deity of Rohini is Prajapati who is considered to be the creative force behind the universe.

The following is from the Mahabharata which gives what is first, taken from Aswamedha Parva: Anugita Parva: Section XLIV.

> "Brahmana said, 'I shall now tell you truly about all that which has a
>   beginning, middle, and end, and which is endued with name and
>   characteristics, together with the means of apprehension. It has been
>   said that the Day was first, Then arose Night. The Months are said to
>   have the lighted fortnights first. The constellations have Sravana for
>   their first; the Seasons have that of dews (viz., Winter) for their
>   first. Earth is the source of all smells; and Water of all tastes. The
>   solar light is the source of all colours: the Wind of all sensations
>   of touch. Likewise, of sound the source is space (or Ether). These are
>   the qualities of elements. I shall, after this, declare that which is
>   the first and the highest of all entities. The sun is the first of all
>   lighted bodies. Fire is said to be the first of all the elements.
>   Savitri is the first of all branches of learning. Prajapati is the
>   first of all the deities. The syllable Om is the first of all the
>   Vedas, and the life-wind Prana is the first of all winds. All that is
>   called Savitri which is prescribed in this world. The Gayatri is the
>   first of all metres; of all (sacrificial) animals the first is the
>   goat. Kine are the first of all quadrupeds. The twiceborn ones are the
>   first of all human beings. The hawk is the first of all birds. Of
>   sacrifices the first is the pouring of clarified butter on the fire.
>   Of all reptiles the first, O foremost of regenerate ones, is the
>   snake. The Krita is the first of all the Yugas; there is no doubt in
>   this. Gold is the first of all precious things. Barley is the first of
>   all plants. Food is the first of all things to be eaten or swallowed.
>   Of all liquid substances to be drunk, water is the foremost. Of all
>   immobile entities without distinction, Plaksha is said to be the
>   first, that ever holy field of Brahman. Of all the Prajapatis I am the
>   first. There is no doubt in this. Of inconceivable soul, the
>   self-existent Vishnu is said to be my superior. 2 Of all the mountains
>   the great Meru is said to be the first-born. Of all the cardinal and
>   subsidiary points of the horizon, the eastern is said to be the
>   foremost and first-born. Ganga of three courses is said to be the
>   firstborn of all rivers. Likewise, of all wells and reservoirs of
>   waters, the ocean is said to be the first-born. Iswara is the supreme
>   Lord of all the deities and Danavas and ghostly beings and Pisachas,
>   and snakes and Makshasas and human beings and Kinnaras and Yakshas.
>   The great Vishnu, who is full of Brahma, than whom there is no higher
>   being in the three worlds, is the first of all the universe. Of all
>   the modes of life, that of the householder is the first. Of this there
>   is no doubt. The Unmanifest is the source of all the worlds as,
>   indeed, that is the end of every thing. Days end with the sun's
>   setting and Nights with the sun's rising. The end of pleasure is
>   always sorrow, and the end of sorrow is always pleasure. All
>   accumulations have exhaustion for their end, and all ascent have falls
>   for their end. All associations have dissociations for their end, and
>   life has death for its end. All action ends in destruction, and all
>   that is born is certain to meet with death. Every mobile and immobile
>   thing in this world is transient. Sacrifice, gift, penances, study,
>   vows, observances,--all these have destruction for their end. Of
>   Knowledge, there is no end. Hence, one that is possessed of a tranquil
>   soul, that has subjugated his senses, that is freed from the sense of
>   meum, that is devoid of egoism, is released from all sins by pure
>   knowledge.'"

Comment: Can you please add a conclusion ?

Answer (score 6):

I want to make two additions:

> Rama eva param brahma paramatmavidhiyate |
>
> Ramat parataram nasti yatkinchit shulasukshmakaam ||
>
> Brahma Vishnu Shivah sarve indrognirvaruno yamah |
>
> Sarve te Ramachandrasya tejasa sampratisthitaah ||
>
> (**Parashara Smriti quoted in Omkarnath Rachanavali, vol 11, page 396**)
>
> **Meaning**: That Rama is the Para Brahman and Paramatma, Who is the source of all including Brahma Vishnu Shiva.

---

> Vishnu Narayanadini naamani chamitanyapi |
>
> Taanimsarvaani devarshe jataani Ramanamatah ||
>
> (**Padma Purana quoted in Omkarnath Rachanavali, vol 11, page 399**)
>
> **Meaning**: That all names like Vishnu and Narayana arise out of Rama nama.

---

Answer (score 4):

**Rāma Rāma**

Yes, There are Many proofs to Prove that Lord Rāma is the source of all Vishnu tattvas.

Srī ādi Rāmāyana (quoted by Dharma samrat swami karpatri ji in Bhagvata sudha and Accepted by goswami Tulsidas ji) 1.9.18 says :-

> एते चांशकलाश्चैव **रामस्तु भगवान् स्वयम्** ।
> ब्रह्मा विष्णुश्च रुद्रश्च महेन्द्रः श्रीस्तथैव च ॥१८॥
> All the incarnations mentioned above are kala and ansha avatars **but
> Lord Rāma Himself is Bhagvana**, the source of all incarnations.
> Brahma Vishnu Rudra Mahendra and also Sri are parts of **Rama.**

Similar statements are there in,

Sri Maharamayana,

> एते चांशकलाः सर्वे **रामस्तु भगवान् स्वयम्**

Sri Shiva samhita 5.2,

> अवतारास्तु बहवः कला अंशा विभूतय।।
> **रामो धनुर्धरः साक्षात्सर्वेशो भगवान् स्वयम्**

Sri sudarshan samhita 1.5,

> ऐते चांशकलाः सर्वे **रामो ब्रह्म सनातनः**

Valmiki Ramayana 6.117.8,

> त्रयाणामपि लोकानामादिकर्ता **स्वयं प्रभुः**

Lord Rama is the Source of Narayana and all incarnations,

Adbhuta Ramayana 14.12,:-

> योऽपि नारायणोऽनन्तो लोकानां प्रभवाव्ययः।
> ममैव परमा मूर्ति: करोति परिपालनम् ।। १२ ।।
>
> Similarly, Narayan, who is endless and infinite, is the supreme Lord
> of all the worlds created by Brahmaa" and who is imperishable and
> eternal, sustains, nourishes, protects and generally takes care of the
> creation' **as my supreme representative and my embodimen** and he has
> all the characteristic virtues, powers and potentials that I have.

Śrī Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa 7.104.9,

> ततस्त्वमसि दुर्धर्षात्तस्माद् भावात् सनातनात् ।
> रक्षार्थं सर्वभूतानां विष्णुत्वं उपजग्मिवान् ॥
> After my prayers in the begining of the creation, Oh Rama ! You **forsake Your durdharṣa (the swarupa which is difficult to be achieved for many) eternal Bhava (the eternal two armed Śrī Rāma form) and assumed the form of Vishṇu** for the sake of protection and sustenance
> of all the beings.

Adi ramayan 4.24.22

> स्थुलं सुक्ष्मं परं विभुं राममहसांचितम्।
> अवतारांस्तथा सर्वाश्चतुर्विशदशादिभिः।
> The almighty supreme personality of godhead shri ram is greater than greatest and smaller than smallest and is **the source of all 24 and 10 incarnations.**

Padma samhita,

> मरीचमणडले संस्थं बाणाद्यायुधलाच्छितम्द्वि।
> हस्तम् एकमवत्र च रुपाधिकं हरेः ।।
> In the sun , there is **the primeval (original) form of shri hari with two face and one head wielding bow and arrow.**

Brihad Brahma Samhita 2.7.8,

> वासुदेवादि मुर्तिनाम् चतुर्नाम् कारणं परम्।
> चतुर्विंशति मुर्तिनाम् आश्रय श्रीरामः शरणं मम।।
> The supreme cause of the four vyuhas, such as Vasudeva. Sri Rama, the **shelter of the twenty-four avtars**, is my refuge.

Adi Ramayana 1.6.29-31,

> हनुमानुवाच धन्योऽसि कृतकृत्योऽसि गरुड त्वं हि संप्रति ।
> सकुलस्त्वं पुनीतोऽसि राघवेन्द्रस्य दर्शनात् ॥ २९ ॥
> श्रीरामे देवदेवेशे कोशलायां विराजति ।           अंशावतारा: कृष्णाद्याः प्रणमन्ति ह्य संख्यकाः ॥३०॥
> न ततोऽन्यमहं जाने देवदेवं खगेश्वर ।           सर्वावतारनिधेश्च रघुवीराद् गुणाकरात् ॥ ३१ ॥
> Sri Hanuman says, "Lord Śrī Rāma of Ayodhya is the God of all the Gods. **Lord Shri Krishna and other incarnations are his Amsha Avataras of Lord Śrī Rāma.** Those innumerable incarnations make salutations to
> Lord Shri Ram. I don't know any other Supreme Being, the god of all the gods other than that Lord Ram. **All the innumerable incarnations are originated from Lord Shri Ram alone.**"

Ending with a shloka from Mahabharata, Harivamsa parva, chapter 41, shloka 249,

> गाथा अप्यत्र गायन्ति ये पुराणविदो जनाः।
> रामे निबद्धतत्त्वार्था माहात्म्यं तस्य धीमतः ॥       १४९ ।।
> In the case of Sri Rāma, those who Believe that Sri Rāma is the Highest Truth, the One learned in puranas sing the following glories,
> which tells about the Greatness of Lord Rama

Answer (score 1):

**vAlmiki rAmAyaNa - yuddha khanda - sarga 117 mentions rAma as source of all incarnations:**

*भवान्नारायणो देवः श्रीमांश्चक्रायुधः प्रभुः || ६-११७-१३
एकशृङ्गो वराहस्त्वं भूतभव्यसपत्नजित् |

"You are the **Lord Narayana** himself the glorious god, who wields the discus. You are the **Divine Boar** with a single tusk, the conqueror of your past and future enemies."

शार्ङ्गधन्वा हृषीकेशः पुरुषः पुरुषोत्तमः || ६-११७-१५
अजितः खड्गधृग्विष्णुः कृष्णश्चैव महाबलः |

"You are the wielder of a bow called Sarnga, the lord of the senses, **the supreme soul of the universe**, the best of men, the invincible, the wielder of a sword named Nandaka, the all-pervader, the bestower of happiness to the earth and endowed with great might."

सेनानीर्ग्रामणीश्च त्वं त्वं बुद्धि स्त्वं क्षमा दमः || ६-११७-१६
प्रभवश्चाप्ययश्च त्वमुपेन्द्रो मधुसूदनः |

"You are the leader of the army and the village headman. You are the intellect. You are the endurance and the subduer of the senses. **You are the origin and the dissolution of all, Upendra the Divine Dwarf and (the younger brother of Indra) as also the destroyer Madhu, the demon**."

सहस्रशृङ्गो वेदात्मा शतशीर्षो महर्षभः || ६-११७-१८
त्वं त्रयाणां हि लोकानामादिकर्ता स्वयंप्रभुः |
सिद्धानामपि साध्यानामाश्रयश्चासि पूर्वजः || ६-११७-१९
जगत्सर्वं शरीरं ते स्थैर्यं ते वसुधातलम् || ६-११७-२६
अग्निः कोपः प्रसादस्ते सोमः श्रीवत्सलक्षणः |

"**The entire cosmos is your body**. The earth constitutes your firmness. Fire is your anger. The moon constitutes your placidity. You are Lord Vishnu (who bears the mark Srivatsa - a curl of white hair on his breast)."
"In the form of the Vedas, you are the great Bull with hundred heads (rules) and thousand horns (precepts). **You are the first creator of all, the three worlds**, and **the self constituted Lord of all**. You are the refuge and the forbear of Siddhas (a class of demi-gods endowed with mystic powers by virtue of their very birth) and Sadhyas (a class of celestial beings.)"

त्वया लोकास्त्रयः क्रान्ताः पुरा स्वैर्विक्रमैस्त्रिभिः || ६-११७-२७
महेन्द्रश्च कृतो राजा बलिं बद्ध्वा सुदारुणम् |

"**In the past, the three worlds were occupied by you in your three strides**, after binding the exceptionally formidable Bali (the ruler of the three worlds) and Indra was made the king (by you)."*

**harivamsha - harivamsha parva - chapter 41 also mentions rAma as source:**

*Scholars well-read in the purANA-s, **who consider rAma as the source of all truths**, have sung this hymn in honour of that intelligent one... "rAma, the king of ayodhya, had a blue-black hue, black eyes, nectarine speech, and shinning face; arms extending up to his knees he has a beautiful countenance and leonine shoulders. That high-souled king rAma ruled the kingdom for eleven thousand years, in which kingdom the chanting of the Rik, yajur and sAma Vedas is continually heard, along with the twang of bows, together with encouraging the utterances like: make gifts to people... feast the people with finest viands..." The energetic and accomplished son of dasharatha, namely rAma, shinning in his own effulgence, surpassed even the sun and the moon in his lustre. Having celebrated hundreds of holy sacrifices with perfect and most excellent gifts the highly powerful rAghava left ayodhya and repaired to the celestial region Having thus brought about the destruction of demon rAvaNa with all his kinsmen, the omniscient and mighty-armed rAma, the descendant of ikshvAku dynasty, returned to the region of the celestials...
Having thus brought about the destruction of demon rAvaNa with all his kinsmen, the omniscient and mighty-armed rAma, the descendant of ikshvAju-s, returned to the region of the celestials..*

Answer (score 1):

**ततस्तवमसि दुर्धर्षात्रस्माद भावात् सनातनात्।
रक्षार्थ सर्वभुतानाम् विष्णुसं उपजग्मिवान्।।**

Valmiki Ramayan7.104.9

Kaal says:- After my prayers, in the beginning of creation, you forsaken your durdharssa form(form that is difficult to be achieved by so me many) the bhava (2 armed Shri Ram) and assumed the form of Vishnu (narayan) for the sake of protection and sustenance of all living beings.

**वासुदेव आदि रूपाश्च अवताराः प्रकीर्तिताः ।
तेषाम ऐश्वर्य दातृत्वात् स्वयं पूर्णोत्तमोत्तमम् ॥
इति रामो विग्रहवान्स्वयं ब्रह्म सनातनः ।
आत्मारामश्चिदानन्दो भक्तानुग्रहकारकः ॥**

(इति महेश्वर तंत्र~ भगवान शिव उवाच)

English meaning:-

Vāsudeva (#shri_krishna) and other forms of the incarnations (#narayan, #narsimha, #varah, #dattatreya, hayagriva) have been described. Because shri Ramchandra Himself is the giver of their (all avtar’s) opulence, He Himself is the best of the best. Thus Rama, the eternal Brahman, himself.He is always blissful and bestows mercy on His devotees.

**नारायण सहस्राणि कृष्णाद्याः शतकोटयः।
कोटि कोट्यवताराश्च जाता रामांघ्रिपंकजाम्॥**

(Shiva samhita)

सहस्त्र अवतारी नारायण एवं शत कोटि अवतारी कृष्ण तथा करोड़ो करोड़ों अवतार जैसे वाराह, नृसिंह, वामन , दत्तात्रेय, हयग्रीव इत्यादि, श्री जगन्नाथ श्रीसीतानाथ रामजी के चरणचिह्नों से प्रकट होते हैं

Thousands of avtari shriman narayan, hundreds of crores of avtari krishna and crores of crores of avtars like varah, narsimha, vaman, dattatreya, haygriva etc, are appearing from footprint of bhagwan shri Ramchandra.

**परान् नारायणाश्चैव कृष्णात् परतरादपि।
उभयपरातमनः श्रीमान् रामो दशरथि स्वराट।।**

(~नारदपंचरात्र अन्तर्गत आनंद संहिता).

नारायण तथा कृष्ण से भी परे महाराजा दशरथ के पुत्र भगवान श्री राम ही हैं, उनसे परे कोई भी नहीं है।

Lord Shri Ram, the son of Maharaja Dasaratha, is beyond Narayan and Krishna; there is no one beyond him.

**वासुदेवादि मुर्तिनाम् चतुर्नाम् कारणं परम्।
चतुर्विंशति मुर्तिनाम् आश्रय श्रीरामः शरणं मम।।**

(Brihād Brahmā Samhitā 2.7.8, Śrī Hāri Nāräyana to Brahmā)

The supreme cause of the four vyuhas, such as Vāsudeva. Śrī Rāma, the shelter of the twenty-four avtars, is my refuge.

**बहवोवतारश्च सकला अंशविभुतयः।
रामो परात्पर साक्षात् भगवान् परमेश्वरः।।**

~hanumat samhita

There had been so many ansha, kala, vibhuti avtars but shri Ram is the only supreme among all avtars and supreme personality of godhead and parmeshwar

**येऽवतारा विभोः मुग्धे जायन्ते विश्वहेतवे।
तेऽपि रामांघ्रि चिह्नेभ्यः समभवन्ति पुनः पुनः।।
सर्वे चांशकलाभुताः शक्ति वीर्य कलान्विताः।
रामचन्द्राघ्रि संजाताः रामस्तु भगवान स्वयम्।।**

(~Māha Rāmāyan)

हिन्दी अनुवाद:-

जितने भी अवतार ( #परनारायण, #कृष्ण, #नृसिंह, #सदाशिव, #पराशिव, #महाशिव , #महानारायण, #नारायण , #महाब्रह्मा आदि ) विश्व के हेतु होते आए हैं वे सब के सब सर्वेश्वर भगवान श्री रामचन्द्र के पैरों के चरणरेखा से उत्पन्न होते हैं। जितने भी कला अवतार, अंश अवतार, विभुति अवतार, वीर्य अवतार, शक्ति अवतार होते हैं वे सब के सब सर्वेश्वर भगवान श्री रामचन्द्र से उत्पन्न होते हैं इसलिए श्रीराम ही भगवानों के परमेश्वर हैं।

Hindi translation:- All the incarnations (#ParaNarayan, #Krishna, #Nrisimha, #Sadashiv, #Parashiv, #Mahashiv, #Mahanarayan, #Narayan, #Mahabrahma etc.) have been for the sake of the world, all of them are at the feet of Lord Shri Ramchandra. are generated from. All the art incarnations, partial incarnations, vibhuti incarnations, power incarnations, power incarnations, all of them are born from Lord Shri Ramchandra, therefore Shri Ram is the God of all gods.