# Does Valmiki ramayan says Ram was god or an incarnation?

Tags: ramayana, gods, rama

Can someone help me with the references of Ramayan from Valmiki which says Ram was a god or an incarnation ?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Yes, it is mentioned in several places such as Balakanda, Yudhkanda and Uttarakanda..see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/23262/12304 and https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/27809/12304 and https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14438/3500