# Do any authentic vedic scriptures depict Sri Ram as the only ultimate parabrahman?

Tags: vedas, puranas, ramayana, rama, reference-request

In the present era, many people worship Shri Ram as Bhagavan, many people see him as merely an incarnation, and many people consider him to simly be an ideal man. But other than the Sri Valmiki Ramayana, are there any other authentic scriptures that in one voice introduce Sri Ram as the only supreme person of Vedas and as the ultimate brahman ??

Comment: I don't think there is a text that mention about Shri Ram, because vamiki Ramayan was the first text to mention Shri Ram to my current knowledge. And vedas or vedic text (by the name it self you can understand it must be written in the time of vedas) were written way before Ramayan happened.

Comment: Related [Are there any scriptures that portray Lord Rama to be the source of all incarnations including Lord Vishnu?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/22093/12304)

Comment: [This](https://www.hinduwebsite.com/vedicsection/upanishads/ramarahasya.asp) is Ram Rahasya Upanishad with verses and translation

Comment: @Proxy the date in wiki is about 17 century ce. How it can be vedic text

Answer (score 6):

Yes,Very much. Sri Adi Ramayana 1.9.18 says:-

एते चांशकलाश्चैव रामस्तु भगवान् स्वयम् । ब्रह्मा विष्णुश्च रुद्रश्च महेन्द्रः श्रीस्तथैव च ||

> **All the above mentioned incarnations are Portions or Kalā avatars, but Lord Rāma is the Bhagvana himself. Brahma, vishnu, Rudra and Sri, all are portions of Lord Rama**

Lord Rāma is the Origin of All incarnations, He is Swyam Bhagvāna and Source of All Vishnu tattvas. Next, Sri mahaRamayana (quoted in Sri Upasanatraya siddhanta) repeats the above as :-

एते चांशकलाः सर्वे रामस्तु भगवान् स्वयम् ॥

> **~ All the above mentioned incarnations are Portions or Kalā avatars, but Lord Rāma is Himself the Bhagvāna.**

That's not it, Sri Shiva samhita 5.2 too says:-

अवतारास्तु बहवः कला अंशा विभूतयः ॥ रामो धनुर्धरः साक्षात्सर्वेशो भगवान् स्वयम् ॥

> ~ **There have been many incarnations Which are Kala avatars, Portions or vibhutis, but The Bowman Rama, the supreme Lord, is himself the Bhagvana**

Sri Sudarshana samhita 1.5 also says **ऐते चांशकलाः सर्वे रामो ब्रह्म सनातन** i.e All the incarnations mentioned above are Portions and Kalas of Rama, who is the Eternal Brahman himself.

Srimad bhagvatam 2.7.23 says **kaleśa ikṣvāku-vaṁśa avatīrya** i.e The Lord of all Kalās took birth in the clan of iksvaku i.e Lord Rama is the paripoorna bhagvana.Even Valmiki Ramayana 6.117.18 calls him the original creator and the Prabhu (i.e the Supreme Lord) himself **त्रयाणामपि लोकानामादिकर्ता स्वयं प्रभुः** and Adi Ramayana 4.24.22 clearly states that Lord Rama is the source of All 24 incarnations as **अवतारांस्तथा सर्वाश्चतुर्विशदशादिभिः**, as the Final destinantion where all Avatars merge in 1.87.36 viz.  राम एव लयं जग्मुस्ते सर्वे तस्य पश्यतः, the Supreme source of all Vyuhas of Adi Narayana in 1.13.18 as **अस्य चत्वारेवा अंशाः ब्रह्मरुपाः सनातनाः। वासुदेव संकर्षण प्रद्युम्नश्चानिरुद्धकः** and swyam avatari i. 1.9.18 viz. अवतारी स्वयं राम

sri Ramarahasya upanishad 2.7 states that Narayana, vasudeva(krsna), narasimha, varaha etc are Limbs of Lord Rama, while sri krsna upanishad too states that Lord Rama is swyam bhagvana, who later incarnated as Lord krsna in vrindavana viz. rudrādīnāṁ vacaḥ śṛtvā provāca **bhagavānsvayam**

I have many more examples to prove Rama supremacy, from different shastras, this was just a portion of it.

Answer (score 5):

> यद् ब्रह्मेमहिमाऽपेक्ष्यः तद् रामेति न संशयः।
> ब्रह्म की महिमा देखकर ये निश्चित होता है कि श्री राम ही ब्रह्म है,
> इसमें कोई संशय नहीं है।

(Anand Ramayan Manohar khand sarg 4.196)

Again in same sarg shlok 199,

> तद् रामेति परं ब्रह्म सृष्टि स्थिति अन्त हेतुकम्।
> Ram is the parabrahman,who creates, sustains and destroys everything.
>
> रामं विद्धि परंब्रह्म सच्चिदानन्दम् अद्वयम्।

Shri Ram is the undual parabrahman sachidanand swarup.
Adhyatm ramayan 1.1.32
गृणन्ति सततं वेदा मामेकं परमेश्वर।

Adbhut Ramayan 13.6

> Shri ram is sung as parameshwar in all of the Vedas including
> Mahabharata which is considered as pamcham veda.

Answer (score 4):

**One more reference from authentic scripture:**

**harivamsha - harivamsha parva - chapter 41 mentions rAma as source:**

*Scholars well-read in the purANA-s, **who consider rAma as the source of all truths**, have sung this hymn in honour of that intelligent one... "rAma, the king of ayodhya, had a blue-black hue, black eyes, nectarine speech, and shinning face; arms extending up to his knees he has a beautiful countenance and leonine shoulders. That high-souled king rAma ruled the kingdom for eleven thousand years, in which kingdom the chanting of the Rik, yajur and sAma Vedas is continually heard, along with the twang of bows, together with encouraging the utterances like: make gifts to people... feast the people with finest viands..." The energetic and accomplished son of dasharatha, namely rAma, shinning in his own effulgence, surpassed even the sun and the moon in his lustre. Having celebrated hundreds of holy sacrifices with perfect and most excellent gifts the highly powerful rAghava left ayodhya and repaired to the celestial region Having thus brought about the destruction of demon rAvaNa with all his kinsmen, the omniscient and mighty-armed rAma, the descendant of ikshvAku dynasty, returned to the region of the celestials...
Having thus brought about the destruction of demon rAvaNa with all his kinsmen, the omniscient and mighty-armed rAma, the descendant of ikshvAju-s, returned to the region of the celestials..*

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Rama Rahasya Upanishad declare him as Parabrahma.

> 5-6. He replied, “Hey, great sages and devotees of Lord Vishnu! Please hear my words which cut of all attachments, the greatest principle among these is the principle of Brahma Taraka (Aum). **Rama is Para-Brahma and supreme austerity,** and Rama is the Supreme Essence and Brahma Taraka.”

Rama Tapaniya Upanishad says the same;

> 1.The body has been ascribed to Para Brahman which is holy, without any second, which does not have any blemishes and which is bodiless,
> so that the worshippers are shown the path.
>
> 2.Similar to the whole banyan tree existing in the seed of the banyan tree, the entire world exists in the seed “Rama”.